# x11vnc Web Browser Access

Tags: linux, remote-access, vnc, screen-sharing

**The Problem**
I have a Linux embedded device and I'm trying to share the screen to access it remotely through a web browser using x11vnc. I've searched through multiple posts that explain how to do this but I've had no success. At least I was able to access the shared screen using vnc viewer on my Windows machine.

**What I've done so far**
I start the server with this command: `x11vnc -display :0 -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd -http`
This sets up the screen share, the Java viewer URL is printed (http://imx6ul-var-dart:5800) on PORT=5900. So far so good.

When I open my web browser (chrome) and I type in `<remoteIP>:5800` in the URL bar, I get a blank page with a hyperlink "x11vnc site" that opens a new tab to where you would expect (http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/). Meanwhile, the terminal outputs:
`httpd: get ' ' for <remoteIP>`
`httpd: defaulting to 'index.vnc'`
`httpd: premature connection close` (Once the connection times out ~15seconds)

I tried to use a combination of different command options but nothing that works.

**The Question**
How can you access a screen shared with x11vnc through your web browser?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve a VNC access through your web browser, you will need some kind of proxy. You can install such a proxy on the server (running x11vnc), on the client (running browser) or on another system sitting in-between.

Have a look there, your will find NoVNC software that will probably fit your need :
[noVNC WebSite](https://novnc.com/info.html)

Comment: Thanks! I had a bit of trouble installing noVnc on my device but I finally got it working. I can't connect with my phone yet but that's a separate issue :)